# Custom query_var to get URL paramater not working

Tags: actions, query-variable

I have a custom Wordpress login and if the user gets to the homepage and is not logged in, they are redirected to the custom login form(I have disabled this for now while I test). What I would like to do is create a URL parameter so that certain users can still get to the homepage without having to log in. From my research it seems like this is possible with a custom `query_var`. Right now I am just trying to make it work with anything entered into the new `query_var` and then once I get that working I will make sure it matches a specific value. Here is what I added to my `functions.php`:

```
add_action('init','add_var');
function add_var() { 
  global $wp; 
  $wp->add_query_var('auth');
}
if (get_query_var('auth')) {
  echo 'User is visiting from approved URL';
}
```

I am then adding `?auth=true` to the homepage URL, but this does not seem to be working. Nothing is being echoed out. Any ideas?

Comment: `get_query_var()` won't work if you call it from the root of the functions file like that. You should use later hooks like `parse_query` or `wp`.

Comment: But one would add a custom query var for rewriting purposes or when the var is to be used with the WP query/request. Otherwise, you could simply use `$_GET['auth']` which works anywhere in a PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

The `get_query_var()` function and/or method only works with registered WordPress [`query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/). You can actually view the method via [`get_query_var()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get/).

The normal URL parameters you can access with the normal PHP super global `$_GET`.